# Renaming issue within command prompt

Tags: cmd, command, rename, file-rename

i'm trying to rename a file called Pawn.Stars.S01E02.Hello

i'm using

```
cmd ren "Pawn*Stars*" "Pawn Star$.*"
```

which does rename the file but renames it to Pawn Star$.Stars.S01E02.Hello

i have also tried

```
ren Pawn.Stars*.txt PawnStar$*.txt
```

which gives the same result.

The Name i'm trying to get is Pawn Star$.S01E02.Hello

Where am i going wrong or what needs to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stated what name you are trying to achieve, so I cannot give you a command that works.

But I can tell you that it is not possible to remove or change the dot between Pawn and Star$ using a simple REN command with wildcards. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for an explanation.

One option would be to write a batch script to do the rename. There are also 3rd party utilities that provide more sophisticated file renaming capabilities.

**Update based on comment from OP:**

The following will do the rename from the command line:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b /a-d pawn.stars.*') do @for /f "delims=. tokens=2*" %B in ("%A") do @ren "%A" "Pawn Star$.%C"
```

Double up the percents if you use the command in a batch script.

Comment: The name i'm trying to get is Pawn Star$.S01E02.Hello

but for what ever reason it's keeping .Stars

Comment: @mcolvin - The "for whatever reason" is because that is how the command works - read the link I gave you. I've updated the answer with a command that should work.

Comment: hey dbenham the command you gave me works when the file is in the dir with the script how do i also search sub dir?